# Form Posts custom posts - WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have an wordpress website with twentyseventeen theme.

I wish custom fields like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWG9v.png)  I think I need a form posts plugin.

Searching on google I found [Form to Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/form-to-post/) WordPress plugin, but did not help me.

Also, I tried with Toolset types plugin but it doesn't help me 100%.

I think I need to build this kind of plugin myself.

I am a beginner php / html and I didn't built another plugin or template for wordpress platform.

Could you recommand some tutorials which can help me with this problem please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Multumesc de comment, Andrei Gheorghiu !

Comment: You're welcome. In its current form the question is unclear. You should provide more details on: a) what you want to achieve. b) break it down into things you know how to do and things you don't know how to do. If things you don't know how to do are too many, consider asking each in a different question. Your question should not look like a job that needs done, but like a specific technical programming problem, that could be answered within a few short paragraphs. It should also show your efforts into doing it yourself and what problems you ran into. *"Did not help me"* is not good. See [ask].

Comment: You want to look into two separate subjects and each of them is fairly complex: 1. Create [CPTs](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/). 2. [Add posts](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/posting-via-the-front-end-inserting--wp-27034) from frontend. There are a lot more resources to pick from, I just chose 2 which seemed fairly detailed at describing how each of the tasks can be done. You should expect at least 3-4 hours work on this for the basic functionality alone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

A lot of tutorials on youtube but...
1. [How to create custom post type](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/)
2. [How to display them](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/)
That should help.

**The Second solution is:**

1. Create a template of page which will have a form inside.[How to do custom page template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)
2. Write a code to validation data from a form after submit.
3. Add action to form which is path to your file from point 2.
4. In validation code, if you want to store data in database, you must add (insert, update, select etc.) queries. Get data with $_POST['name of field(input) in a form']

Comment: I trided some plugins:  
Custom Post Type UI, Form to Post, but didn't help me. Also, With Form to Post I created a form with all that fields but when I press submit button, the post is submitted as a simple form with just 2 fields (Title and Conent)

Comment: Like  Andrei Gheorghiu said, you should search for information, do efforts.
I gave you tips, hints, even step by step.

Comment: @Alex, ultimately, you want to perform a [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) with the sanitized result of your form. Look at the structure of the arguments the function takes and add all necessary fields to your form. Make sure you enable [`debug.log`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) or use a debugger plugin to see any errors you might be getting while developing.